# Какая разница между словами "забросить" и "бросить"?

Tags: значение-слов, глаголы, смысл, приставка

Какая разница между словами "забросить" и "бросить"?

Answer (score 1):

У этих слов похожие значения. Если вы сомневаетесь, какое слово правильно употребить, то слово "забросить" не сочетается с глаголами, а "бросить" - сочетается.

Забросить означает "бросить далеко, на какой-то предмет", "забыть, оставить", если речь о хобби, "переместить что-то с целью этим воспользоваться позже" или "помочь кому-то добраться ближе к цели".

Answer (score 1):

Здесь надо разобраться с глагольной категорией вида.
Оба этих глагола совершенного вида соответствует перфекту в западноевропейских. В русском структура глагола иная. В современном русском глагол имеет всего лишь три временнЫе формы (прощедшее, настоящее, будущее), а все дополнительные категории (особенности) передаются исключительно с помощью лексических средств или самостоятельными парными словоформами. Вот у нас для выражения перфекта использовано самостоятельное слово ***"забросить"*** - выполнить действие бросания, с достигнутым результатом.
А ***"бросить"*** - это просто что-то сделать, не смотреть на результат, т.е. полный семантический эквивалент глаголу *"бросать"*, только совершенного вида.

Бросить мяч в корзину - выполнить бросок, мяч может попасть, мождет не попасть .
А если "забросить" - то попал точно.

Сложность русского перфекта (совершенного вида) еще и в том, что такой глагол, если он образуется с помощью приставки, обычно сужает семантическое значение исходной формы. Так некоторые (не основные) значения "бросать"  утрачены в приставочной форме совершенного вида ("забросить"). Как вам верно сказали, можно "бросить курить" (=прекратить), но не "забросить". Зато "забросить" может означать прекращение более длительного процесса. "Забросить работу над диссертацией" это просто давно ей не заниматься в силу каких-то причин. "Бросить" - означало бы окончательное и осознанное решение.

Короче, тут очень много семантических нюансов, всего в ответе не передать. И вообще, каждый конкретный случай для подобной пары надо смотреть по толковому словарю. Здесь я накидал только общий принцип. Я думаю, что вам с подобными вопросами действительно лучше перейти на параллельный "международный" (англоязычный сайт) сайт. Здесь уровень обсуждения рассчитан более на носителей русского как родного, а там лучше чувствуют смысл вопроса и потребности изучающего.